# Data dimensionality problem with tensorflow sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, sequential

Being new to Keras sequential models is causing me a few troubles!

I have an `x_train` of shape : 17755 x 500 x 12

and `y_train` of shape: 17755 x 15 (labels are already one-hot encoded)

And I made the next model to be trained on this data:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,3,padding="same", activation="relu", input_shape=(17755,500,12)))
model.add(MaxPool2D())

model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D())

model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D())
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(15, activation="sigmoid"))

model.compile(optimizer ='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['Accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

1- when I don’t use `np.expand_dims` to add an axis for batch, I get this error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the
> layer: expected shape=(None, 17755, 500, 12), found shape=(None, 500,
> 12)

2- when I do use `np.expand_dims` and the shape of `x_train` became: 1x17755x500x12
I get this error:
Data cardinality is ambiguous:
x sizes: 1
y sizes: 17755
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

3- when I use  `np.expand_dims` for `y_train` too and its shape became: 1x17755x15
I get this error:

> ValueError: Shapes (None, 17755, 15) and (None, 15) are incompatible

I know I’m doing something fundamentally wrong, but what what is that? Can anyone please help me out with the shape of data please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding `x_train` try adding a new dimension at the end to represent the channel dimension needed for `Conv2D` layers. Note also that you do not provide the number of samples to your input shape. Here is a working example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x_train = np.random.random((17755,500,12))
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=-1)
y_train = np.random.random((17755,15))
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,3,padding="same", activation="relu", input_shape=(500, 12, 1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D())

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D())

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.4))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(15, activation="sigmoid"))

model.compile(optimizer ='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['Accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

Comment: It's working ! Thank you! Thank you very much! You don't know how much time I put into this trying figure out the problem! Thanks!

Comment: No stress. Have fun